# Correct way to get Microsoft Active Directory attribute "memberOf" when using DirectorySynchronization

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, ldap

I regularly read out the active directory for an application to store the current state in a database.
To reduce the amount of data I use DirectorySynchronization to get only the changes since the last query.
But now I also need the attribute "memberOf" which is not provided by the DirectorySearcher when using DirectorySynchronization.

At the moment I get the DirectoryEntry for each found entry, but then more attributes are delivered than I need, which contradicts the actual intention.

Is there a way to set which attributes are read with DirectoryEntry, similar to PropertiesToLoad with DirectorySearcher or is there better way to read the attribute "memberOf" when using DirectorySynchronization?

Code excerpt:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(domain, username,password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher dirSearch = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
//filter to user objects
dirSearch.Filter = "(objectCategory=person)";
dirSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";

byte[] cookie = null;
DirectorySynchronization sync = new DirectorySynchronization(DirectorySynchronizationOptions.ObjectSecurity,cookie);
    
dirSearch.DirectorySynchronization = sync;
using (searchRoot)
{
    using (SearchResultCollection results = dirSearch.FindAll())
    {
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            List<string> memberOf = new List<string>();
            PropertyValueCollection prop = dirEntry.Properties["memberof"];
            
            foreach(var member in prop)
            {
                memberOf.Add((string)member);
            }
            
        }
    }
    cookie = sync.GetDirectorySynchronizationCookie();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now I also need the attribute "memberOf" which is not provided by the DirectorySearcher when using DirectorySynchronization.

`memberOf` is a special attribute computed by the directory, so it's not provided by `DirectorySynchronization` (which uses in fact [DirSync control](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/ad/polling-for-changes-using-the-dirsync-control)). The only thing that could provide `DirectorySynchronization` is the directory's real modification, which belongs to a user's DN added to a `group` object in the `member` attribute (which kind of triggers a `memberOf` recomputation)

> At the moment I get the DirectoryEntry for each found entry, but then more attributes are delivered than I need, which contradicts the actual intention.

`GetDirectoryEntry` performs a new directory search and loads all the attributes (it has no link with the `DirectorySearcher` settings and previous search).

So, instead of the `GetDirectoryEntry`, you can use another `DirectorySearcher` (that will load just the `memberOf`) that will do a single search on each loop (example without any strong tests, ie. `null` values etc.):

```cs
using (searchRoot)
{
    using (SearchResultCollection results = dirSearch.FindAll())
    {
        // A new DirectorySearcher
        DirectorySearcher anotherDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
        anotherDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            // A new filter on each loop in order to look for an single entry
            anotherDirectorySearcher.Filter = $"(samaccountname={(string)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]})";
            List<string> memberOf = new List<string>();            
            foreach(var member in anotherDirectorySearcher.FindOne().Properties["memberOf"])
            {
                memberOf.Add((string)member);
            }
            
        }
    }
    cookie = sync.GetDirectorySynchronizationCookie();
}
```

Note that:

```cs
dirSearch.Filter = "(objectCategory=person)";
// Here you override the previous one (the Filter property is a string)
dirSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";
// If you want both, you can use:
dirSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
```